# OSX Keynote files are bundles, can you pares bundles like folders?

Tags: macos, keynote

I need to be able to parse keynote bundles. Do they work like directories, that is, will most languages treat them as a folder?

Comment: I think there have been multiple different keynote file designs, but OS X does recognize some folder structures as a "bundle". This isn't really a language question though, more of how a file is store on the file system. Use Terminal to see if it is a file or a directory.

Comment: Thanks that is  good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing about a "language" treating a bundle as a folder or a file. That's the job of the OS. Mac OS X see bundles as directories, however, *Finder* treats some bundle as a file. You can test this using command line tools:

```
cd MyFile.key
```

Every language, including Apple-made ones like Swift and Objective-C, see them as regular folders. In addition, Apple also provides some tools to deal with bundles, check out the [NSBundle class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html).

Comment: Ah! NSBundle, that may help a lot. Thanks